# Increment digits in file name using regex in shell, mac

Tags: regex, macos, shell

I have shell script

```
for f in *.res;
do
   mv $f ${f/2002/2003}
done
```

It change filename `abcd20020107.res` to `abcd20030107.res`. Here 2002 is year, 01 is month, 07 is day.

I'm not sure, how normal realize script that will take year and increment it. I understood, that it must be something like this

```
for f in *.res;
do
   mv $f ${f/\d\d\d\d/($1 + 1) % 1000}
done
```

But it don't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sed` to increment the year:

```
mv "$f" $(sed -r 's/([^0-9]+)([0-9]{4})(.*)/echo "\1$((\2+1))\3"/e' <<< "$f")
```

The regex splits the filename in 3 parts `\1`, `\2`, `\3` respectively:

- `[^0-9]+`: start of filename not containing digits
- `[0-9]{4}`: the first 4 digits year
- `.*`: the rest of the filename

The increment happens with the `echo $(( )))` using the `e` mode of `sed`.

Note this is GNU `sed` specific (and might not work on other `sed` implementation).

Answer (score 0):

You may also try to use `awk` to do this,

```
mv "$f" $(awk '{match($0,/[0-9]{4}/,a);sub(/[0-9]{4}/,a[0]+1)}1' <<< "$f")
```

Brief explanation,

- `match($0,/[0-9]{4}/,a)`: Find first 4 digit in the filename, and save the matched part into array a
- `sub(/[0-9]{4}/,a[0]+1)`: substitute the matched regex `[0-9]{4}` part with `a[0]+1` in the filename
- The append `1` in the `awk` script would allow to print the `$0`, i.e. filename

Answer (score 0):

A more human readable solution if you have `dateutils` package installed

```
mv "$f" $(dateutils.dadd -S -i "%Y%m%d" -f "%Y%m%d" +1y <<< "$f")
```

- `-i` specify input date format
- `-f` specify output date format
- `-S` sed mode, process only the matched string and copy the rest
- `+1y` adds 1 year